# React Native Project crashes only on iOS release build when using picker

Tags: react-native-ios

I have a React-Native project that works great in iOS simulators but when I create and run a release build it crashes when attempting to use the native picker from "react-native-picker-select". Does anyone have any idea which settings I should check? Is this likely a linking issue of some kind?

Here is part of crashlog.crash that was reported from testflight:

```
Incident Identifier: 6560AA87-73D3-495D-AE8E-1F1B4A78D072
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,1
Process:             myappnative [2637]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C78D8FE8-2A16-4556-866E-23F963E8593F/myappnative.app/myappnative
Identifier:          com.myapp.myapp
Version:             1 (0.1.2)
AppStoreTools:       12C29
AppVariant:          1:iPhone8,1:14
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.myapp.myapp [577]


Date/Time:           2021-01-15 09:06:55.5924 -0800
Launch Time:         2021-01-15 09:04:47.8783 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.3 (18C66)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    8.20.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  8

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1b16399d8 __exceptionPreprocess + 216 (NSException.m:199)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1c59a2b54 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   myappnative                     0x102f85e18 RCTFatal + 668 (RCTAssert.m:145)
3   myappnative                     0x103002314 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatal:stack:exceptionId:suppressRedBox:] + 492 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:76)
4   myappnative                     0x103002d4c -[RCTExceptionsManager reportException:] + 1536 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:145)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1b163e130 __invoking___ + 144
6   CoreFoundation                  0x1b15211d0 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 300 (NSForwarding.m:3389)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x1b1521730 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 76 (NSForwarding.m:3495)
8   myappnative                     0x102fb5cd4 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 460 (RCTModuleMethod.mm:584)
9   myappnative                     0x102fb7e68 facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&) + 244 (RCTNativeModule.mm:114)
10  myappnative                     0x102fb7bcc operator() + 44 (RCTNativeModule.mm:75)
11  myappnative                     0x102fb7bcc invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) + 88 (RCTNativeModule.mm:67)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b1271298 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1454)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b1272280 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:559)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b121adcc _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 612 (inline_internal.h:2548)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b121b8a8 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 424 (queue.c:3862)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b1225338 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 712 (queue.c:6601)
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1f9d335a4 _pthread_wqthread + 272 (pthread.c:2207)
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1f9d36874 start_wqthread + 8
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find anything ? Or we just have to change the lib ?

Comment: Which version of Expo & React Native were you using ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Expo is "~45.0.0" and React Native is "0.6.82".